# How to take thumnails of youtube video

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I want to take and display picture of video is being played i think they are called thumbnails and change every minute, I have displayed video using youtube iframe api, now i want to take pictures of video currently being played and display picture and change every minute, how can i do this? youtube data api?

Comment: So your efforts, what have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? This information would help someone here; help you with your specific problem.

Comment: first are they called thumbnails?

Comment: Show us your code, and show us what exactly you've tried so far. We can't help without knowing what you've done.

Answer (score 0):

For this there are two methods

1. Show Video Thumbnail
2. Show Image Thumbnail For Video

#### Show Video Thumbnail:-

```
YTPlayerView *thumbnailView=[[YTPlayerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
[mainPlayerView loadWithVideoId:Enter Video Id];
[self.view addSubView thumbnailView]
```

#### Show Image Thumbnail For Video

```
UIImageView *imageView=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
        NSString *strURl=@"YouTube Video Id Here";
        NSString *strMain=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://img.youtube.com/vi/%@/mqdefault.jpg", strURl];

//sd_setImageWithURL
// if not using  sd_setImageWithURL then load image from data 
        [imageView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strMain]];
        [self.view addSubview:imageView];
```